# Trick to ensure that "only" rvalues can exist of a particular class?

Tags: c++

Is there any trick in C++ that can ensure that a user of a class can generate only rvalues?

Example:

```
struct PoorClass { /* ... */};

struct EnrichedClass {
    explicit EnrichedClass (const PoorClass & poor)
        : m_poor (poor)
    {
    }

    /* additional functionality for poor objects */

private:
    const PoorClass & m_poor;
}

const EnrichedClass asEnriched (const PoorClass & poor)
{
    return EnrichedClass { poor };
}
```

Now enriched objects should be only temporaries, as they should not survive the wrapped poor objects. Ideally, enriched objects should never be stored in a variable, but only passed as rvalue references to functions.

Is there any way to ensure that, i.e., to get this as fail-safe as possible?

Comment: how EnrichedClass is converted back to PoorClass? If you add inheritance, then returning via value is wrong (you will loose all 'enrichement' on return).

Comment: There's some problem with your code... How can you convert an EnrichedClass into a PoorClass, as the function asEnriched requests?

Comment: It is not converted back at all. `EnrichedClass` has some member functions that are useful for objects of type `PoorClass`, yet are, unfortunately, not defined there, and I cannot / do not want to change `PoorClass`.

Comment: Sorry, typo -- corrected.

Comment: My best idea so far: Make `EnrichedClass` non-copyable. Yet this does not answer my question.

Answer (score 6):

You may provide only r-value methods for `struct EnrichedClass`:

```
struct EnrichedClass {
    explicit EnrichedClass (const PoorClass& poor) : m_poor (poor) {}

    /* additional functionality for poor objects */

    void foo() &&; // note the && at the end.


private:
    const PoorClass & m_poor;
};
```

Comment: OP mentions "pass[ing] as rvalue reference[...] to functions". Your `foo` may not be invoked in that context unless the lvalue inside such a function is explicitly cast to an rvalue. Which in turn allows `foo` to leave the object in an unspecified state, making subsequent calls to other members  potentially problematic.

Comment: @Pixelchemist any non-const-qualified method can leave the object in an unspecified state, regardless of whether it's rvalue qualified or not.

Comment: @ecatmur That's true but rvalue qualification of an object usually indicates something like "ownership will end here". The idea of something like `std::move(obj).foo(); std::move(obj).bar();`  appears odd to me. :)

Comment: @Pixelchemist as long as you're aware of that - I've noticed a tendency to attribute magical properties to `std::move` such that after it's been called `obj` can't be used or will be in an empty state - which is actually only the case for a minority of types e.g. `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @ecatmur There are many things I don't consider "advisable" or "good style" which *may* well be done when handled correctly / cautiously. If I'd find something like I had in my last comment, I'd stop short and wonder what's going on. Nevertheless, sometimes the only way to achieve certain behaviour is unusual (and requires good documentation).

Answer (score 4):

Afaik, there's no way to achieve the desired task directly.

I can think of one way of somehow 'working around the problem':

**Make a private or protected constructor and copy constructor with a named static construction function.**

Something along the lines of:

```
struct PoorClass { /* ... */ };

struct EnrichedClass
{
  EnrichedClass& operator= (const EnrichedClass & enr) = delete;
private:
  explicit EnrichedClass(const PoorClass & poor)
    : m_poor(poor)
  { }
  EnrichedClass(const EnrichedClass & enr)
    : m_poor(enr.m_poor)
  { }

public:
  static EnrichedClass enrich(const PoorClass & poor)
  {
    return EnrichedClass{ poor };
  }
  void stuff() { }
private:
  const PoorClass & m_poor;
};
```

Thus, one cannot copy the instance:

```
EnrichedClass::enrich(p).stuff(); // works
auto ec = EnrichedClass::enrich(p); // does not
```

Note: One may still have lvalues of `EnrichedClass` via rvalue-references.

```
void foo(EnrichedClass && e)
{
  // e = lvalue here
}
```

About the rvalue-ref qualification idea:

```
void bar() && { /* do stuff */ }
```

If you want to pass your rvalue to a function using rvalue-references you cannot call member function with `&&` ref qualification since rvalue-references are still lvalues (i.e. `e` is not an rvalue inside `foo` above).

You could do:

```
void foo(EnrichedClass && e)
{
  std::move(e).bar();
}
```

But now you have provided a guarantee for `bar`: The object referenced by `this` is an rvalue. It is fine to do whatever you like as long as the object is in a valid (yet unspecified) state after the call (i.e. `bar` can move from `this`).

Thus, after calling `bar` you may not know the state of `e`.

Comment: Looks like a change in C++ made this answer obsolete, `auto ec = EnrichedClass::enrich(p);` compiles with C++17.  I had the same solution in one of my classes and I discovered today that it doesn't work anymore. I think it has to do with copy elision being more explicit now.

Answer (score 2):

It looks that you can do the trick with :

- have private constructors in EnrichedClass
- make `asEnriched(PoorClass)` return an EnrichedClass&&

Here is an example :

```
#include <iostream>

struct PoorClass {
    // trace construction and destruction
    PoorClass() {
        std::cerr << "Create " << this << std::endl;
    }
    ~PoorClass() {
        std::cerr << "Destroy " << this << std::endl;
    }
};

struct EnrichedClass {
private:
    EnrichedClass (const PoorClass & poor)
        : m_poor (poor)
    {
    }
    EnrichedClass(const EnrichedClass& rich): m_poor(rich.m_poor){}

    /* additional functionality for poor objects */

    const PoorClass & m_poor;

    friend const EnrichedClass&& asEnriched (const PoorClass & poor);
    friend void dump(const EnrichedClass& rich); // only to be able to access m_poor
};

const EnrichedClass&& asEnriched (const PoorClass & poor)
{
    return EnrichedClass ( poor ); // gives a warning, but seems harmless
          // provided the ref in only used as a parameter to a function call
          // of course don't affect it to a true ref, or do not take the address
          //  if you do not want dangling refs or pointers !
}

void dump(const EnrichedClass & rich) {
    std::cerr << "Dump " << &(rich.m_poor) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
   PoorClass poor;
   // EnrichedClass rich = poor; causes an error
   // EnrichedClass rich = asEnriched(poor); causes an e};
   dump(asEnriched(PoorClass()));
   std::cerr << "End" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

That displays :

```
Create 0xbfbfec58
Create 0xbfbfec50
Dump 0xbfbfec50
Destroy 0xbfbfec50
end
Destroy 0xbfbfec58
```

meaning that the reference is valid for the duration of the dump call while it is impossible to affect an `EnrichedClass` to a variable.

Of course, you could affect a reference. For example `const EnrichedClass& ref = asEnriched(poor);` would be accepted, but will give you a dangling ref.
I cannot imagine a way to force the compiler to detect that as an error - after all it already gave a warning for `asEnriched` returning a reference to a temporary ...

Comment: Why would returning a reference to a local temporary be `harmless`?

Comment: @Pixelchemist : it is harmless here because OP just wants the `EnrichedClass` to be passed to a function and not to survive the call of the function. And I showed that it actually works like that. But I have also said that if you affect if to a true reference you get a *dangling* ref. May be I should be more explicit about that ...

Comment: I'm aware of that, sorry. My point is that OP wants it to be `as fail-safe as possible` where in my opinion returning references to local temporaries introduces some quite remarkable pitfalls.  More clear now :)

Comment: You are _literally_ returning a dangling reference to a temporary, as the temporary will get destroyed once the `asEnriched()` method will be left. "Seems to work" because you entered the realm of Undefined Behavior, so the compiler can do whatever it likes, but you cannot depend on it in any portable way.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the question, not sure of my answer.
but I think you can achieve this by hiding `Poor` inside `Enriched` and overload the `Poor` operator:

```
class Better{
    class Poor{};
    Poor& m_Poor;

public:

    Better(class Poor& poor) :m_Poor(poor){}
    operator Poor(){
        return m_Poor;
    }

};
```

you can't create Poor directly since it's private. you can only provide some r-value and pass `Better` as `Poor` becuase it has converting operator.

Comment: The point about the question is that JohnB wants to provide an interface layer for `Poor` without touching it and with the Interface class being rvalue only.